# In rails, should I include user input form error flows on capybara (or integration) tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara, integration-testing, acceptance-testing

Rails supports several types of tests:

- Model tests
- Controller tests
- Functional tests
- Integration tests

And, with capybara, it can also support:

- Acceptance/integration/feature (depends on the author) tests

On some sites I see that these acceptance/integration/feature tests should only test particular flows, leaving edge cases for other kinds of tests. For example:

> Integration tests are used to test the interaction among any number of controllers. They are generally used to test important work flows within your application.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing

> While these are great for testing high level functionality, keep in mind that feature specs are slow to run. Instead of testing every possible path through your application with Capybara, leave testing edge cases up to your model, view, and controller specs.

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-we-test-rails-applications

But I also see things like:

> Your goal should be to write an integration test for every flow through your app: make sure every page gets visited, that every form gets submitted correctly one time and incorrectly one time, and test each flow for different types of users who may have different permissions (to make sure they can visit the pages they're allowed to, and not visit the pages they're not allowed to). You should have a lot of integration tests for your apps!

https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/lessons/integration-testing-with-capybara

So, that's my question: In rails, should I include user input form error flows on capybara (or integration) tests?

Or do you think it should be enough to write view tests to test for the existance of flash messages, test failure flows via controller tests with the assigns helper, and only test successful flows through acceptance/integration/feature tests?

**Edit** The accepted answer was due to the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User input form errors are handled by [Active Record validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) in Rails. So you could cover these with [unit tests](http://www.rubytutorial.io/testing-rails-validations/). But those kinds of tests only verify that you have validations present on your model. I'm not sure how much utility these types of tests offer other than allowing you to recreate your models in another framework or language and still have your tests pass.

Comment: Yes, Active Record validations can be tested through unit tests, although I tend not. I think it makes sense what DHH has to say about it: "Don’t test standard Active Record associations, validations, or scopes." [Testing like the TSA](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3159-testing-like-the-tsa). Regarding capybara tests, I was wonder if I should test that errors are being correctly displayed. What do you think?

Comment: Maybe a single UI test that tests for the presence of flash messages in general. If the flash message is present as a part of the application layout it shouldn't need to be tested for every separate use case.

Comment: I usually prefer having error messages near to the input with the error instead of a general flash message. Would it be a good idea to test only one failure case per form?

Comment: There are a number of ways to handle error messages including client-side javascript. I would test only one instance for each. If your error displaying code is modular you can just test the module and possibly that it is included on the page.

Comment: Interesting. I like the idea to try to extract the code used to show form errors and unit test that part and that it's included. I'll try that. Thanks.